# jQuery plugin to do rotate/flip animation without inverting content?

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate, flip

I want a jQuery plugin to help me do a flip animation on a `div` element on the x axis while preserving the background image and without inverting the content.  I've tried a few plugins but unable to achieve the result I'm looking for.  If anyone can suggest a solution, that will be great.  Here's what I tried so far, but no success:

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ - i am able to use the rotateX, and the card content is visible while rotating, but I don't wnat the content to be inverted after the rotate.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/ - same problem as the plugin above

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ - This one does not invert the content, which is great, but it uses a solid background color while flipping, instead of preserving the content of the card.

Does anyone have a solution to the problems I'm encountering?

Comment: **Quote:**  _"...flip a div element on the x axis while preserving the background image and without inverting the content."_  ~ It's not clear what you want.  If you don't touch the background or content, then nothing has flipped.

Comment: I do a 180 degree flip on div element.  When that happens, all the text and images in the div element is backwards and upside down, as if looking at a mirror while upside down.  I like the flipping action, but I want the orientation of the text and images in the div element to stay the same.

Comment: Oh ok, you never mentioned "animation".

Comment: Additionally, I'm doing a `$('div').html('insert new content here')` half-way through the animation. So that it looks like i'm flipping into new content.  The new content is inverted and upside down after teh flip.  I tried doing 2 flips...one flip with animation 5000 ms and hte second animation with 0ms at 2500 ms, to try to quickly revrse the flip.  But the result of the second flip does not take effect.

Comment: Instead of searching for flip plugins.  Why not search for image slider plugins that also have a flip animation effect?  Typically the image sliders allow you to use any kind of element in addition to images; and these will not invert content.

Comment: That's a good idea.  Are there any you worked with that might do the job? I intend to flip a series of 10 to 20 div elements one after another.  Each div element is a search result containing information about an athlete (so a photo fo the person, with a caption under neath).  So hopefully these animations won't experience performance issues.

Comment: Nivo & Cycle come to mind as two with lots of advanced animation effects.  I'm sure there are dozens of others.

Comment: i have tried something just have a look to it http://jsfiddle.net/W4Ne9/7/

Comment: @fuzionpro - I'm on chrome and the contnet is still inverted and upside down

Answer (score 0):

Why not have nested divs, one as the container of the background image, and the other for the content.

Just invert the div containing the background-image